# How can i move a car which will follow a curver path

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to make a car move/rotate along a curved path. I would like to set the wheels's and car's orientations depending on that path.

I can set an initial orientation but what about the rest of the path?

(This is what I've tried

```
var agl = Math.atan2(
  this.latLonG[0].lat - this.tiler.lastBbox.c.lat//this.latLonG[0].lat 
  ,this.latLonG[0].lon - this.tiler.lastBbox.c.lon//this.latLonG[0].lon
  );
```

**NOTES:**

1. I need to deduce what point on a spline the car is on at each frame. How do I do that given I want to complete the path in 5 seconds ?
2. I want to be able to control speed : how to implement it ?

Comment: Could you explain with more details pls? I still not understand fully your question: You want the car to follow a path, how is your path defined? How the car need to be moved along the path?

If I am correct, you want the car to react in a standard/realistic way and following the line (for a AI car)?

Comment: I have THREE.car object. need it to follow a curve say random spline curve with proper orientation ie if  I set moveForward=true the car will run on the path. I have given 2 conds.

Comment: So what you need is a function that: given a point on the line, return a point on the same line some "x" meters further? then orientation of the line in this point and the radius of the curve at this same point will give you the car position, orientation and wheel orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move a car along a curve, following its orientation :

1. You first need to define the main points of a spline
2. Then create this spline
3. Increase a number that represents where the car is on the curve, between the start (0) and the end (1)
4. And make the car look at a point one step further.

   ```
   //1. create spline's points
   var points = [
       new THREE.Vector3( x1, y1, z1 ),
       new THREE.Vector3( x2, y2, z2 ),
       ...
       new THREE.Vector3( xn, yn, zn )
       ];

   //2. create spline
   var spline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( points );
   //since r72. Before : THREE.SplineCurve3

   //3. define the car position on the spline, between its start (0) and end (1)
   var carPositionOnSpline = 0;

   //Then at each increment (in your render loop or in the 'update' function of a tween)
   var newPosition = spline.getPoint( carPositionOnSpline );
   car.position.copy( newPosition );

   //Also update the car's orientation so it looks at the road
   var target = spline.getPoint( carPositionOnSpline + .001 );
   car.lookAt( target );//+.001 or whatever
   ```

To make the wheels turn you can get the cross product of the orientation vector and the previous orientation vector. Assuming you are moving a car on the plane of the axis x and z, the wheel's orientation will be proportional to the y value of the resulting vector :

```
var actualOrientation = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors( target, newPosition );
actualOrientation.normalize();

var orientation=new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors( actualOrientation, previousOrientation );

wheel.rotation.y = something * orientation.y;

previousOrientation = actualOrientation;
```

Comment: thanks @Atrahasis, the orientation is quite good , but at some point car rotated 180 deg reverse( can be fixed). Your ans is somewhat base on my first NOTE. From yours I got orientation solved but I want the car to move in a certain time say 5 sec in the path say:
    [new THREE.Vector3(-100,0,100),new THREE.Vector3(10,0,-10),
     new THREE.Vector3(50,0,-50), new THREE.Vector3(40,0,10), new   THREE.Vector3(100,0,100)]

based on frame(60 fps) * time I can travel but I don't want to depend on fps.

Comment: I don't understand at all :-)

Comment: this code
var newPosition = spline.getPoint( carPositionOnSpline );
car.position.copy( newPosition );
with increment allows the car to follow the points on spline curve. It will not assure that the car will reach  spline.getPoint(1) position at certain time say 5 sec. how to make sure?

Comment: This is another question. Have you searched it before asking ? Let me rephrase this question : 'how to tween a value in a given duration ?' :) In case you do not want to implement a tween, if you are ok with a linear movement, your problem is 'how to get the elapsed time from the previous frame ?' You would have to make some additions and divisions in your render loop to deduce the point on the spline given that time. This is quite easy and I would feel bad for you to spare you that.

Comment: @ Atrahasis, I dont want  the elapsed time from the previous frame(THREE.Clock() i guess). My question is simple dont think in a huge way. I have 
1. Mesh Object
2. A path eg spline curve
The mesh should travel from one end of curve to another end in 5 sec. How?(I can use 60fps * 5=300 points and can copy it to mesh so normally it will take 5 sec but I dont want that fps dependency) correct me if wrong!

Comment: You don't need to copy points. If you want to tween linearly from 0 to 1 in 5 sec, you write `spline.getPoint(carPositionOnSpline)` inside your loop. Your question is about how much `carPositionOnSpline` has to be incremented before. It is `carPositionOnSpline += elapsedTime/5000` where `elapsedTime` is the time since last frame in milliseconds. It is a real shame this division requested 6 comments and i don't think you've searched it long...

Comment: with this its done:
var et=this.clock.getElapsedTime();
this.carPositionOnSpline=et/5; (5 sec  // here millisec not helpful)

//or var delta=this.clock.getDelta();
//or this.carPositionOnSpline+=delta/5;

if(this.carPositionOnSpline>1){this.carPositionOnSpline=1;}

I dont want to comment on "shame" but at the end I got the fish.  Thanks Again.